# Is one rails server per application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

I have two questions about rails server:

1. Do I have to start the server from within the application folder?
2. Is the server I started only for that application?

If they are true, this does not quite make sense to me, since why do I need to start multiple servers?

Or is there  some kind of master configuration, so that one server can route to different applications?  Is Capistrano for this purpose?

Comment: no distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)), "thanks" should never be part of a question text.

Comment: Use nginx/apache with phusion passenger.. to run more than one Rails application.. google it you can get more info..

Comment: To Anthon: ok, thanks:)
To: Raj. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're talking about the `rails server` command, for running a local rails server to test your application, and that you're not talking about setting up a rails application on a remote server. Please mention if that is not the case.

1. Yes, you must execute `rails server` from within the root folder of your rails application.
2. Yes, the server you started is only for that application. It's a self-contained thing.

You should not need to start multiple servers. Even if you have multiple applications, you probably don't need to have more than one running at a time. So, you can shut down the rails server in one application (Ctrl-C) and then `cd` to your new application, and start a new rails server there with `rails server`.

If you do need to run two local rails applications at once, you can do so by running them on different ports. So, the first one, you can just execute `rails server` and it will make your site available at `localhost:3000` (because port 3000 is the default port). The next one, you can specify a port *other* than 3000 - eg. `rails server -p 3001` to get a rails app at `localhost:3001`.

Capistrano is for deploying your applications to a remote server, not for running them locally on your own computer. So, it is not relevant here. What you may be interested in is http://pow.cx/

Again, I've assumed you're talking about running your rails app locally on your own computer. If you're referring to deploying it to the internet on a server, then you can ignore this answer.

Comment: Yeah, i was talking about "rails server". Thanks for the answer. So basically,
Webrick is not like apache. Is that what "thin" is about?  can i configure
it to be running just one process and route to different applications?

Comment: That's a while other question in it's own right. You should read up on the difference between 'web servers' and 'app servers', I think it will make things more clear. This is a very brief explanation: http://rorguide.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/difference-between-application-server.html

Comment: And lots more info in different Ruby app servers here: https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/ruby-app-server-arena-pt1

Comment: Thank you so much Joshua for the resource.

Comment: No problem. If you found the answer to be correct, consider marking it as such.